# Backup Agendado no Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, backup, microsoft-azure

Sei que os backups no SQL Azure são automáticos, mas como posso fazer uma configuração neles? Agendar para determinada hora?

Answer (score 0):

NÃO é possível configurar a frequencia dos backups no Azure SQL. Confesso que não vejo necessidade para tal, visto que ocorre back a cada 5-10 minutos. Vide trecho da documentação sobre [com que frequência os backups ocorrem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups#how-often-do-backups-happen).

> Os backups de banco de dados completos ocorrem semanalmente, os
>   backups de banco de dados diferenciais geralmente ocorrem em horários
>   determinados e os backups de log de transações geralmente ocorrem a
>   cada 5 a 10 minutos.

Isso quer dizer que pode-se restaurar os dados com precisão de intervalos de 5-10 minutos.

A unica configuração que pode ser feita é com relação ao [tempo que os backups são armazenados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups#how-long-do-you-keep-my-backups). Hoje eles segue a seguinte regra:

- A camada de serviço Básico é de 7 dias.
- Camada de serviço Standard é de 35 dias.
- Camada de serviço Premium é de 35 dias.

Mas pode-se [extender o período de retenção dos backups](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups#how-to-extend-the-backup-retention-period). Isso permite que você estenda o período de retenção interno de 35 dias para até 10 anos. Para obter mais informações, consulte [Retenção de longo prazo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention).